# dpkg - how to install pre-dependency?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg, dependencies

I need to install apt package on a Western Digital DL4100 NAS running a Linux DL4100 distribution where the only package system is `dpkg`. To do so, I have to install multiarch-support, it depends on `libc6` which depends on `libgcc1`. But `libgcc1` pre-depends on `multiarch-support`.

There is no file containing `yum`, `pacman`, `apt`, `aptitude`, `portage`, `dselect`, `emerge` or `zypp` in its name on the disc. I have found only `dpkg` in `/var/lib/dpkg` and `/usr/bin/dpkg`.

How can I install these packages where one package depends on another package which pre-depends on the first one?

```
# dpkg -i /path/to/libc6.deb /path/to/multiarch-support.deb /path/to/libgcc1.deb
```

returns

```
dpkg: package libgcc1 pre-depends on multiarch-support, which is not installed or flagged to be installed
```

There is no package installed under dpkg:

```
# dpkg -l
    Name           Version
+++-==============-==============
```

Comment: `dpkg` pre-depends on `libc6`; are you sure `libc6` is not already installed?

Comment: I am sure, it is not installed.

Comment: How did you end up with a system like that? You say "the only package system is `dpkg`" — but since `dpkg -l` doesn't list anything, `dpkg` isn't actually managing anything on the system...

Comment: dpkg is the only package manager i have found on disc. So... how can i find out which pm its present. Is kernel 3.10.38 64-bit

Comment: Yes, it is Western Digital NAS DL4100.

Answer (score 4):

In theory, on a `dpkg`-managed system, you should be able to install multiple packages in a single operation; this will allow installation of packages with a dependency loop. Assuming you have the appropriate packages downloaded:

```
dpkg -i libc6_*deb multiarch-support_*deb libgcc1_*deb
```

will install `libc6`, `multiarch-support` and `libgcc1`.

On a Western Digital NAS though, even if the operating system is based on Debian (there are some indications that it is), installed software isn't managed using `dpkg`, and fixing that is both quite difficult, and quite likely to break your system further down the line. To install software on your NAS, you should [use the features available in MyCloud](http://setup.wd2go.com/?mod=faqs&device=mcdl4100&faq=thirdParty).

(A `dpkg`-managed system should **never** require the above packages to be forcefully installed, since they are dependencies of `dpkg` itself.)

Comment: No, it will not - see my question.

Comment: similar issue for me except libgcc1 depends on libc6, this solved the problem ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to install the packages using some of the `--force-...` flags of `dpkg`,
use `--force-help` to list them. The ultimate way is the `--force-all` flag.

It could be needed that you need to unpack some of the packages manually, and trying the installation again.
Having a look at `debootstrap`, which need to solve the same problem, can also be helpful.

Comment: Using `debootstrap` here is just a recipe for disaster... It should only be used if you know Debian well enough to attempt to replace the NAS's operating system with it.

Comment: @StephenKitt I did not want to suggest using debootstrap, but would suggesting looking in its source code, how it solves the dependency problem.

Comment: I understand, but trying to solve the dependency problem manually using `debootstrap`-inspired techniques is also likely to cause problems. This isn't a `dpkg`-managed system, trying to forcefully turn it into one seems unwise to me.

Answer (score 0):

1. `sudo dpkg --force-all -i <.deb filename>`
2. `sudo apt install -f`

These two commands worked flawlessly and will work on all softwares.

Comment: The `--force-` options should not be used lightly.  The `dpkg` man page has this to say of them:
"Warning: These options are mostly intended to be used by experts only. Using them without fully under‐standing their effects may break your whole system."

Comment: but this is the only solution.

Comment: It is not the only solution: two of the answers to this question don't involve `--force` at all.  However, the downvote was because of the sweeping claim that this "will work on all softwares":   How thoroughly did you test it?  (The OP specifically mentioned that `apt` isn't available.)  What do you even mean by "softwares" -- packages, or distributions?  If the results are "flawless", why is there an emphasized warning against it in the man page?

Comment: my answer is only for debian based operating systems, and here software means packages, and packages also are software, also I have tested this in which installation I was getting error.

Answer (score -1):

Find a machine where `apt-get` is installed and run the follow command:

```
apt-get --print-uris --yes install YourTargetPackage | grep ^\' | cut -d\' -f2 | xargs wget
```

It will download all dependencies to your machine.

Then you can copy this dependencies on your machine with `dpkg-only` and download all dependencies:

`dpkg -i pathToFolderWithDeps/*`

Then install your app:

`dpkg -i YourTargetPackage.deb`

Comment: Your first command can be greatly simplified using `apt-get`'s `--download-only` option. But it won't download "all dependencies" to your machine, only those which are missing from the machine it's run on. To retrieve all the dependencies you'd need to use `apt-rdepends`.

Comment: In my case on "proxy" machine all dependencies may by already installed, so we would not get required packages to download. So I have use this long command to be sure that all dependencies will be downloaded. And I try to avoid install extra packages, and ```apt-rdepends``` command usually is absent.

Comment: The long version doesn't change the fact that you won't get all the dependencies...

Comment: would the --reinstall flag for apt-get install work?